# A mod B, A and B are very large numbers

Tags: modulo, largenumber, bignum

I want to know if A and B are relatively prime using Euclidean Algorithm. A and B are large numbers that cannot be stored in any data type(in C), so they are stored in a linked list. In the algorithm, the operator `%` is used. My question is, is there a way to compute for A mod B without actually directly using the `%` operator. I found out that `%` is distributive over addition:

```
A%B = ((a1%B)+(a2%B))%B.
```

But the problem still persists because I will still be doing `%B` operations.

Comment: You want the [Binary GCD Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

You need calculate `a % b` without the `%` operator. OK? By definition the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) finds the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) after division of one number by another.

In python:

```
# mod = a % b
def mod(a, b): 
    return a-b*int(a/b)

>>> x = [mod(i,j) for j in range(1,100) for i in range(1,100)]
>>> y = [i % j for j in range(1,100) for i in range(1,100)]
>>> x == y
```

> True

In C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

unsigned int mod(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    return (unsigned int)(a-b*floor(a/b));
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=sizeof(unsigned int); ++i)
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=sizeof(unsigned int); ++j)
            if (mod(i,j) != i%j)
                cout << "Somthing wrong!!";
    cout << "Proved for all unsigned int!";
    return 0;
}
```

> Proved for all unsigned int!

Now, just extend the result to your big numbers...!!!